# Find repeating dates within a specific range

Tags: php, mysql, sql

*It's my first post on stackoverflow, so please tell me if my question doesn't fit the rules here properly.*

I'm trying to implement a search in PHP/Mysql which will find all entries within a specific time range, where the entries specify on which weekdays they are valid.

This is the database model:

```
CREATE TABLE offer (
    offer_id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    start int unsigned not null,
    primary key(offer_id),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE offer_weekdays (
    offer_id int unsigned not null,
    weekday tinyint unsigned not null,
    index (offer_id),
    foreign key (offer_id) references offer(offer_id) 
          ON delete restrict ON update cascade,
    unique key (offer_id, weekday)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The table *offer* describes an entry and from when (column *start* (timestamp)) it is available. The table *offer_weekdays* specifies on which weekdays the entry is repeated. Each entry may be repeated on several different weekdays.

I want to implement a function which fetches all entries that are available in a specific timestamp range. My ideas to solve this problem are either slow or lacking accuracy.

I appreciate any hint. Thanks in advance!

**Example**:

The following entries are stored in the database:

1. Start: 2011-01-11 10:00 (Tue), repeated: Tue
2. Start: 2011-01-11 08:00 (Tue), repeated: Tue
3. Start: 2011-01-12 12:00 (Wed), repeated: Wed, Thu, Fri

The searched time range is from 2012-01-10 09:00 (Tue) to 2012-01-11 11:00 (Wed).

**Result:**

1. found
2. not found. It fits the weekday range but is only valid at 08:00 but
   the search is from 09:00.
3. not found. It is valid at 12:00, but the search is until 11:00.

If the searched time range overlaps one whole week all entries should be found.

Comment: So you don't store an end time for an offer?  If you want all the offers for 2012-01-19 to 2012-01-25, would that be every offer that starts on or after 2012-01-29? (Because that time period covers every weekday.)

Comment: I added an example to make it clearer. On any further questions just ask me.

Comment: Typos in years or weekdays in your example?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to select when

```
The offer starts within the search interval, OR
(the offer starts *before* search interval and 
 start time of the offer >= start time of the search range 
 as long as repeating weekdays match)
```

I'm really, really not sure I got that right. So I'm going to take a different look at the problem. I'm also going to use SQL timestamps instead of Unix epochs, so everyone can see what's going on.

Also, I'm assuming offers end at midnight, more or less. There seems to be no other assumption that makes sense to me right now.

```
create table offerings (
  offer_id integer not null,
  offer_start timestamp not null,
  offer_end timestamp not null check (offer_end > offer_start),
  primary key (offer_id, offer_start)
);

-- Offer 1 starts 2012-01-10 10:00, ends 2012-01-10 23:59, repeats every Tue.
insert into offerings values (1, '2012-01-10 10:00', '2012-01-10 23:59');
insert into offerings values (1, '2012-01-17 10:00', '2012-01-17 23:59');
insert into offerings values (1, '2012-01-24 10:00', '2012-01-24 23:59');
insert into offerings values (1, '2012-01-31 10:00', '2012-01-31 23:59');

-- Offer 2 starts 2012-01-10 08:00, ends 2012-01-10 23:59, repeats every Tue.
insert into offerings values (2, '2012-01-10 08:00', '2012-01-10 23:59');
insert into offerings values (2, '2012-01-17 08:00', '2012-01-17 23:59');
insert into offerings values (2, '2012-01-24 08:00', '2012-01-24 23:59');
insert into offerings values (2, '2012-01-31 08:00', '2012-01-31 23:59');

-- Offer 3 starts 2012-01-11 12:00, ends 2012-01-11 23:59, repeats every Wed, Thu, Fri.
insert into offerings values (3, '2012-01-11 12:00', '2012-01-11 23:59');
insert into offerings values (3, '2012-01-12 12:00', '2012-01-12 23:59');
insert into offerings values (3, '2012-01-13 12:00', '2012-01-13 23:59');

insert into offerings values (3, '2012-01-18 12:00', '2012-01-18 23:59');
insert into offerings values (3, '2012-01-19 12:00', '2012-01-19 23:59');
insert into offerings values (3, '2012-01-20 12:00', '2012-01-20 23:59');

insert into offerings values (3, '2012-01-25 12:00', '2012-01-25 23:59');
insert into offerings values (3, '2012-01-26 12:00', '2012-01-26 23:59');
insert into offerings values (3, '2012-01-27 12:00', '2012-01-27 23:59');
```

Now the selection is dead simple.

```
select * 
from offerings
where offer_start >= '2012-01-10 09:00'
  and offer_end   <= '2012-01-11 11:00';

offer_id   offer_start           offer_end
--
1          2012-01-10 10:00:00   2012-01-10 23:59:00
```

So if you can build a view that returns the same results as this offerings table, you can just query the view.

There are three lessons here.

1. Don't let what you have confuse you. Look for what you need.
2. Remember the Easter problem. (Just because you *can* calculate something doesn't mean you *should*.)
3. After simplifying it to the offerings table, I'm *still* not sure I understand the criteria.

---

Later, after comments and corrections . . .

```
-- PostgreSQL
create table offerings (
  offer_id integer not null,
  offer_at timestamp not null,
  primary key (offer_id, offer_at)
);

-- A little data for offer 1. Inserts for 2 and 3 are similar.
insert into offerings
select 1 offering_id, '2011-01-11 10:00'::timestamp + (n || ' days')::interval offer_at
from generate_series(0, 1000, 7) n
where '2011-01-11 10:00'::timestamp + (n || ' days')::interval  < '2012-03-01';
```

The query, again, is dead simple. (And, with a little luck, actually correct this time.) Both these queries will return only offer number 1.

```
select *
from offerings
where offer_at between '2012-01-10 09:00' and '2012-01-10 11:00'

select *
from offerings
where offer_at between '2012-01-10 09:00' and '2012-01-11 11:00'
```

The best thing about them is that, assuming the underlying data is correct, it's obvious that the queries are doing the right thing.  And it's a lot easier to troubleshoot data than to troubleshoot code.

Comment: For each repeating weekday you store a new offering, right? That will cause too much data and maintenance as I would have to add entries continuously by a background job for future dates.

Comment: Just to make my comment clearer: When searching from 2012-02-24 09:00 to 2012-02-25 11:00 it should also give me the offering 1.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work with searches smaller 1 day. When searching from 2012-01-10 09:00 to 2012-01-10 11:00 it will not find offer 1.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate one specific timestamp for each offer each weekday during the search? Maybe we can calculate an offset (first day of the week with 00:00) and have this formular for each offer: offer_weekday_stamp = offset + timeOf(offer.start) + 86400 * offering.weekday

Comment: @Normalo: Look closely at your sample data; you might have a typo or two in there.

Comment: @Normalo: You said, "When searching from 2012-02-24 09:00 to 2012-02-25 11:00 it should also give me the offering 1." Why? That range is from Friday morning to Saturday morning, and offer 1 repeats on Tuesdays. Offer 3 repeats on Fridays; I think that range should return offer 3.